# How to Tally Up Numerical Values and Produce One Value for all Documents in Mongo/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do what should be a rather simple operation in my mongoDB/Node environment. Every document in the collection I'm targeting has a field "openBalance", which is a number value. All I want to do is find the `totalOpenBalance` by adding all of those together.

So far, in reviewing the MongoDB documentation, both $add and $sum seem to be used to perform an operation on the individual documents within the collection, rather than on the collection itself.

This leads me to wonder, is there a different way I should approach this? I've tried numerous constructions, but none work. Here is my function in full:

```
exports.getClientData = async function (req, res, next) {
    let MongoClient = await require('../config/database')();
    let db = MongoClient.connection.db;

  let search, skip, pagesize, page, ioOnly = false, client;
  let docs = [];
    let records = 0;

  if (_.isUndefined(req.params)) {
      skip = parseInt(req.skip) || 0;
      search = JSON.parse(req.search);
      pagesize = parseInt(req.pagesize) || 0;
      page = parseInt(req.page) || 0;
      client = req.client || '';
      ioOnly = true;
  }
  else {
      skip = parseInt(req.query.skip) || 0;
      search = req.body;
      pagesize = parseInt(req.query.pagesize) || 0;
      page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 0;
      client = req.query.client || '';
  }

  search = {};

  if (skip === 0) {
      skip = page * pagesize;
  }

  if (client) {
    let arrClient = [];
    arrClient = client.split(",");
    if (arrClient) {
      // convert each ID to a mongo ID
      let mongoArrClient = arrClient.map(client => new mongo.ObjectID(client));
      if (mongoArrClient) {
        search['client._id'] = { $in: mongoArrClient };
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(search);

  let counter = 0;
  let count = await db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).count();

  let totalClients = await db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).count({ $sum: "client._id" });
  console.log('totalClients', totalClients);

  let totalOpenBalance = await db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).count({ $sum: { "$add" : "openBalance" } });
  console.log('totalOpenBalance', totalOpenBalance);

    db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).skip(skip).limit(pagesize).forEach(function (doc) {
        counter ++; {
      console.log(doc);
      docs.push(doc);
    }

    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            if (!ioOnly) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res(err);
            }
    }
        if (ioOnly) {
            res({ sessionId: sessID, count: count, data: docs, totalClients: totalClients, totalOpenBalance: totalOpenBalance });
        }
        else {
      res.send({ count: count, data: docs, totalClients: totalClients, totalOpenBalance: totalOpenBalance });
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I am getting the total number of clients with this code:

```
  let totalClients = await db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).count({ $sum: "client._id" });
  console.log('totalClients', totalClients);
```

That works perfectly, adding up the instances of a client and giving me the total.

Again, to be crystal clear, where I'm running into a problem is in summing up the numerical value for all of the `openBalance` values. Each document has a field, `openBalance`. All I want to do is add those up and output them in a variable titled `totalOpenBalance` and pass that along in the response I send, just like I do for `totalClients`. I have tried numerous options, including this:

```
  let totalOpenBalance = await db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).count({ $sum: { "$add" : "openBalance" } });
  console.log('totalOpenBalance', totalOpenBalance);
```

and this:

```
  let totalOpenBalance = await db.collection('view_client_data').find(search).aggregate({ $sum: { "$add" : "openBalance" } });
  console.log('totalOpenBalance', totalOpenBalance);
```

... but as I say, none work. Sometimes I get a circular reference error, sometimes an `aggregate is not a function error`, other times different errors. I've been wracking my brain trying to figure this out -- and I assume it shouldn't be that complicated once I understand the required syntax. How can I get my `totalOpenBalance` here?

By the way, the documents I'm targeting look something like this:

```
    {
        "_id": "3hu40890sf131d361f1ad908",
        "client": {
            "_id": "4ft9d366121j04563be0b01d6",
            "name": {
                "first": "John",
                "last": "Smith"
            }
        },
        "openBalance": 128,
        "lastPurchaseDate": "2018-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sum` is an accumulator operator that must appear within a `$group` or `$project` [aggregate pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/). To also incorporate your `search` filter, you can include a `$match` stage in your pipeline.

```
let result = await db.collection('view_client_data').aggregate([
    {$match: search},
    {$group: {_id: null, totalOpenBalance: {$sum: '$openBalance'}}}
]).next();
console.log(result.totalOpenBalance);
```

Comment: Aha! The first of your two constructions DOES work. Guess it needed the '_id' to make it work. Thanks so much, @JohnnyHK!

Comment: A key here is that the `next()` needs to be included for this to work. I hadn't tried that beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I think `$group` is what you're looking for.

So for example to calculate all the `openBalance` fields

```
db.view_client_data.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group: {
           _id : null
           totalOpenBalance: { $sum: "$openBalance" },
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

this should give you an object back like `{totalOpenBalance: 900}`

Here is the mongodb documentation for some more examples 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

Comment: Tried adding `_id: null`?

Comment: Looks like adding `next()`, as in the answer above, is essential to get it to work.